# html5 and css3 video background

Tags: html, css, video, background

I would like to learn how to put a background video in html just like its done at https://vimeo.com

My container width is 1000px.

What size and resoultion should the video be to load faster and be perfect size? Not have black on the top and at the bottom.

Also, can anyone help with the html5 and css3 coding? Can you show me the code?

I would like to follow your instrucktions and teach myself on how to recreate the video in the bg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a video jQuery plugin, like the one from http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/ in order to make a video background with javascript.

Here's my code for it:

```
<video  src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

And my CSS

```
video {
  display: block;
  height: 150%;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: -25%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Basically, what it does is that it positions the video so that it's a) under the content (z-index: -1) and b) larger than the screen.

`Object-fit` allows us to change the way the video reacts to being over or undersized. I chose cover because I assumed that having some of the video cut off wouldn't matter. `fill` will cause it to take the space up, ignoring aspect-ratio. Contain is the default. This method does get rid of black bars.

However, you should also make sure to test out video backgrounds on multiple devices and sizes. A more advanced method that would get rid of black bar issues would be calcuating aspect ratio with javascript and then placing the appropriate source into the DOM. Media queries may also be helpful.